# Check if date field is empty LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

How to check if date type lightning input is empty? I tried using a property say "dateProperty" which contains value of date input field and in JS used condition like, `if (!empty(dateProperty))`
but got error like  [empty is not defined].Then i tried something like
`if (dateProperty!= undefined)` also
`(dateProperty!= null)` but got error like [dateProperty is not defined].Not sure how to go about it or why am i getting UNDEFINED error?

Comment: Can you provide more code to show what you're doing? Preferably build an example in the [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground)

Comment: I tried everything but finally realized the issue is i was not using "This." in front of property name.

Answer (score 1):

You simply check the value of the input field, the same as you'd do for most other types as well.

[Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/ZypM6hG4a/1/edit).

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    dateCheck = 'Not Checked';
    check(event) {
        this.dateCheck = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input').value? 'Populated': 'Not Populated';
    }
}
```

---

```
<template>
    <lightning-input type="date" label="Demo">
    </lightning-input>
    <lightning-button label="Check" onclick={check}>
    </lightning-button>
    Date Check: {dateCheck}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

SFDC Fox's answer will work but I'd like to propose an [alternate approach (playground)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/3S_8UpAfc/1/edit).

HTML:

```
<template>
    <div class="app slds-p-around_x-large">
        <lightning-input 
            type="date" 
            label="Demo" 
            onchange={handleDateChange}
        ></lightning-input>
        <lightning-button 
            label="Do Action" 
            onclick={doAction} 
        ></lightning-button>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    @track dateValue;

    handleDateChange(event) {
        this.dateValue = event.detail.value;
    }

    doAction(event) {
        if (this.dateValue) {
            console.log('win');
        } else {
            console.log('lose');
        }
    }
}
```

Some advantages to this approach:

- Just in time Field Level validations
- Dependent picklists
- Etc.

[Here is a full component](https://github.com/gnerb/Salesforce-Samples/tree/master/ContractorSearch) that was developed with this approach.